# Can LittleBigPlanet2's engine be used for other?

Tags: console

LittleBigPlanet2 just came out. I've worked with the original LBP level editor a bit and really enjoyed it. I've read that LBP2's featureset in the game is much richer; is it possible to use these advanced features to create different sorts of game other than just a regular platformer? I imagine that something along the lines of a Breakout clone would definitely be manageable, but I'm interested in hearing more about the capabilities of the platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it can: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afjZUFRNLqc If you google for various game "genres" along with "LittleBigPlanet 2," there are plenty of other examples.

Comment: Thanks; it seems the vibrant beta community is already way ahead of me. I've even heard rumblings of a rudimentary FPS!

Comment: I've seen a video of a Wolfenstein-3D-style raycasting FPS, but it was pretty rudimentary; it looked like they were rendering using a grid of square columns that were made visible or invisible to represent surfaces in the world.